# Tutorial on how to write a simple JHipster module

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I am very new to JHipster and am trying to figure out how to write a basic "Hello World" JHipster module. I think I understand the basic process of what JHipster does, but information about writing a module is a bit lacking.

The section about modules and blueprints on the JHipster site (https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-module/) brushes on the topic and then pushes the reader off to "Here, go look at the 'fortune cookie' example and, basically, figure it out yourself". Not exactly helpful.

The fortune cookie example requires that you have a database installed and running and that the module will somehow (by magic, I guess) connect to it. This prevents me from running it to see what it does and how it works.

Why is there no simple-stupid-basic "Hello World" example that requires nothing other than some code and JHipster installed?

In any case, I have tried to stumble forward as best I know and try to understand some of the moving parts behind the scenes. Now we start getting into Javascript, and I'll admit, I know very little about Javascript. It's not that hard to figure out, but without some sort of context and detailed documentation of the libraries being used, a neophyte such as myself, is quickly lost and does not know where to turn.

Does anyone know of any **simple** JHipster module examples?

Comment: I think you are confused. A module is a way to extend the power of JHipster, don't you mean an Entity instead?

Comment: No. I need to understand how to write a JHipster module.

Comment: The https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-module does exactly that: creating a "hello world" module